# AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient in IPhone background not working

Tags: iphone, ambient

Im just trying to play a simple audio file.  Here is the scenario,  the app is started and i "prepare to play" the audio on viewdidLoad.  When i go into the BACKGROUND i need to play music for a brief moment but it wont play in ambient category but `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` works fine.  I need it to be ambient category so the user can mute  the sound if they want.

```
-(void) startRing
{
    {
        OSStatus error;
        UInt32 value;


        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
        value = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(value), &value);


        if (error) 
            NSLog(@"couldn't set kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker!");
        [ringTonePlayer play];
        NSLog(@"ringing  %s",[ringTonePlayer isPlaying]?"true":"false");//this always shows false when im in the background
        self->ringing = true;
    }
}
```

in my info plist im putting that this app uses audio in the background as a background mode. the issue is i need to START the audio while in the background but the system wont let me in ambient mode.

Comment: link below seems to show that ambient category in the background is not possible .... but i need the mute button to work ...this is rather  ridiculous of apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763942/avaudioplayer-using-ambientsound-session-is-not-playing-when-app-is-in-backgro